# is it possible to query project access for users via REST-API in VersionOne

Tags: rest, versionone

I tried the following:

`http://<instance_details>/rest-1.v1/Data/Scope?sel=Name,Members.Name,Owner.Name,Workers.Name,Viewers.Name`

this categorises the users in three groups, members, owner and Viewers, however this doesn't gives the role name of each member against the project.

is it possible to query "Member Roles" for any project in VersionOne via REST-API ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The VersionOne API does not expose methods to manage individual project roles.   The only information in reference to roles that you can get for each Member is the default role. Members.DefaultRole.Name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ProjectRoles](https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Getting_Started/Platform_Concepts/Endpoints/Project_Member_Endpoint) endpoint that can provide you role information.

For example,

```
http://<instance_details>/API/ProjectRoles/ByProject?where='Scope%3A12345'
```